# Duvida simples sobre produção de site

Tags: javascript, html

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um site pela minha primeira vez com as tecnologias HTML + CSS + JAVASCRIPT. Estou enfrentando bastantes desafios, e procurando resolver da melhor maneira possível.

Estou criando este layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde serão colocados os dados de usuários, cada usuário tem os seus próprios dados pessoais, então irei chamá-los em uma base de dados externa que chegarão a pagina em formato JSON [links, nomes, tarefas, títulos, detalhes, valor_de_progresso], mas não sei quantos dados cada Usuário terá. Por esse motivo, não é algo fixo, para resolver o problema, passou em minha mente programar o layout em javascript, pois quando a pagina for executada ela ira trazer os dados do usuário e preencher.

E me deparei com a seguinte questão:

Só existe realmente essa possibilidade, de fazer os dados aparecerem por intermédio da javascript?

Estive observando o youtube como exemplo pois a sugestões de videos dados por ele não é uma coisa fixa, e sim algo momentâneo que só por atualizar a pagina alguns videos já não são mais exibidos!

Gostaria de mais possibilidades de pesquisa, pois ate agora não encontrei outra maneira dentro de minhas pesquisas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So uma observação: Estou considerando que você está começando na área.

Para layout, como já foi mencionado você pode usar o bootstrap. Porém se possível tenta criar tudo do zero, pois você vai entender bem mais fácil os frameworks para css.

Também tem bancos de dados em JavaScript e são bem fáceis de usar. Talvez seria até mais aconselhável para você. Mas nada impede de você usar o php ou o nodejs para se comunicar com o MySql e PostgreSQL por exemplo.

Segue algumas sugestões de bancos em js: (Se não me engano alguns slava os dados em arquivos)

1. https://agnostic.github.io/LocalDB.js/
2. https://pouchdb.com/
3. http://taffydb.com/

Comment: Ta bem, irei dar uma olhada, mas sim, neste projeto que estou desenvolvendo estou fazendo do zero muitas das coisas, ja sou programador em outras linguagens

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Cara, creio que não é a única maneira existente, até porque existe várias maneiras de se fazer a mesma coisa. Mas por todas que eu já conheci, essa parte usando o Javascript ( principalmente com o auxílio do JQuery ), seria sua melhor opção. Justamente porque você pode fazer a chamada desses dados através do uso do AJAX, fazendo com que sua aplicação não precise ficar dando reload e requisitando o banco de dados após cada ação que o usuário fazer, o que faria o site ficar lento tanto para usabilidade quanto para o desempenho em si. Usando o AJAX, ele já trás todos os dados que você " pede " e necessita trazer para o front-end e não fica fazendo outras requisições, deixando o site mais dinâmico e " leve ".

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou estudar sua ideia!

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que para o que você quer tem várias maneiras de fazer, php por exemplo você encontra muito conteúdo na internet e é bem intuitivo. Agora na questão do layout você pode usar bootstrap, que mexe com containers para te auxiliar nessa criação, por que se você prescisar fazer algo muito repetitivo quando for trazer os usuários, você consegue padronizar isso com um forEach por exemplo.

Comment: Esta bem obrigado!